# How to validate that a text field only contain A-Z, a-z, space, hyphen in Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

How to validate that a text field only contain A-Z, a-z, space, hyphen in Codeigniter, if possible let me know how can i add new rule to form validation, NOT callbacks, What do i have to do in CI core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is extend the Form Validation class.

Create a new php file inside `application/libraries`, name it `MY_Form_validation.php` and add this code inside:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function my_custom_rule($str){
        return ( ! preg_match("/^[A-Za-z- ]*$/", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

}
```

This will add a new rule `my_custom_rule`

Comment: Another option is creating a `callback` method in the correspond controller. check the [callbacks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) in validation class document.

Comment: @HashemQolami OP specifically stated he didn't want to use calbacks